# Welcome screen in my app with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I developed a app using fragments and a Navigation Drawer.
On the whole it works perfect. The only thing that I would like to add is a welcome screen on the startup.

At the moment the app shows a empty screen with the Navigation Drawer after starting up because the content_main.xml contains only the 'FrameLayout' that not looks very nice.

I have already a fragment Welcome so that I just need to show it on startup of the app.

My code in the MainActivity.java looks like this.

```
 package com.example.petra.accessibilitydemonstration;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)
 findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
 R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


}

public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {



    Fragment fragment = null;
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_welcome) {
        fragment = new WelcomeFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_table) {
        fragment = new TableFragment();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_table_accessible) {
        fragment = new TableAccessibleFragment();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about_us) {
        fragment = new AboutFragment();

    }

    if (fragment != null){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        ft.replace(R.id.screen_area, fragment   );
        ft.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) 
findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}


}
```

Can some one explain what I have to do in order to solve this problem, please,

Petra

Comment: Sorry i can't understand what you try to say. Add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

That startup screen is commonly known as Splash screen. Take a new activity with a layout having ImageView or you can also set the welcome image to the layout background.

Declare this Welcome activity as launcher activity in AndroidManifest.xml file.

It seems you are new to the android development world, if it's true then there are multiple online courses available, I would suggest you to start with completing or learning from one course https://in.udacity.com/courses/android